# Deferred Execution on Changing Data Set

Tags: c#, linq, deferred-execution

I want to use deferred execution to my advantage for updating changing data in a data grid view when the view is filtered. Currently I have an array of rows which can be filtered and the filtered data can then be searched. I use linq queries to filter the data and search the data. I've summarized how I do this below.

```
IEnumerable<SomeDataRowType> m_mainData =
  (select from someDataContext
   new SomeDataRowType {
     properties...
   }).ToArray();

IEnumerable<SomeDataRowType> m_filteredData =
  m_mainData.Where(r => r.SomeProperty == someValue);

IEnumerable<SomeDataRowType> m_searchedData =
  m_filteredData.Where(r => r.SomeProperty.Contains(someSearchTerm));

myDataGridView.DataSource = new SortableBindingList<SomeDataRowType>(m_searchedData.ToArray());
```

Now this works great if the `m_mainData` data set doesn't change.  I can clear the search query and drop back to the filter query, or drop them both, or just apply the search query.  Unfortunately if the `m_mainData` set DOES change then `m_filteredData` and `m_searchedData` filter execute on the old `m_mainData` data set instead of the new updated one.  I sort of understand why this is, but I don't know what my options are to work around this.

I apologize if any of this is unclear.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is `SortableBindingList<T>` here, and how exactly does it operate? AFAIK that is not a BCL class. But the implementation matters: if it basically populates a list or array internally (which would make sense - binding-list is usually heavily `IList`-focused), then there may be no way of solving this, except to rebuild it when needed.

Comment: Simply a custom class that allows the data grid view to be sorted by multiple columns quite easily.  I build a new SortableBindingList whenever the filter or search changes.

Answer (score 1):

To make `m_mainData`, `m_filteredData` and `m_searchedData` deferred, simply remove the `ToArray()` in the top statement:

```
IEnumerable<SomeDataRowType> m_mainData =
  (select from someDataContext
   new SomeDataRowType {
     properties...
   });
```

Note, however, that I strongly suspect that your `SortableBindingList<T>` internally populates a list of some form: data-binding in the winforms/wpf/etc model is heavily `IList`-based, and `SortableBindingList<T>` suggests a custom class related to `BindingList<T>`. If this is the case, the *binding-list* will *never* be deferred - so you will probably need no simply rebind as necessary. Or even better: just *maintain the binding-list directly* - the entire point of a binding-list is that it propagates change notifications.

Comment: In this case I'm only using the SortableBindingList, a custom class derived from BindingList to allow the data grid view to sort multiple columns more easily.

Comment: @user2213625 You have 2 options: re-bind the list (of course without calling `ToArray()`) or perform the filter directly on your `List`. That's what I can understand in this answer.

Comment: @user2213625 right; and `BindingList<T>` is `IList<T>`-based: it *doesn't work* against `IEnumerable<T>`. Presumably you are doing `ToList()` or similar in the constructor. Basically, that class *is not intended* to be used with deferred execution.

Comment: My apologies, I've updated the original post to clarify, I call ToArray() when creating the BindingList.